# This is driving me insane

Tags: riddle

[image]

The hint does not help. We've been stuck on this for hours

Comment: Hi, could you provide the source for this puzzle? Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally: "**We**'ve been stuck on this for hours"

Answer (score 2):

As the hint suggests

> MIRROR-ing upside down

maybe the answer is

> WE

as the result of

> mirroring "ME".

Comment: It's a bit confusing as it's not mirrored but actually rotated.

Comment: @rhsquared oof you're right

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

> I will always see you within me.

Explanation:

> Assuming the aphorism is,about close friends or lovers. 'We' are you and me, the letter 'w' is a rotated 'm', friends or lovers do complement each other while having a significant common base, so it makes sense to see the other upon introspection, looking from 'behind the mirror'. Metaphorically speaking one rotates the POV. On the other hand, watching one's image in the mirror, to some extent one sees what constitutes the other.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously:

> I will always see **reflections** within me - refering to the two reflections needed to restore the mirror to normal. Could be talking about [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-reflection) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection).